# Reversing a password-hashing function knowing plaintext + output

Tags: hash, passwords, reverse-engineering, salt, password-hash

I have a password that has been stored and I'd like to figure out how it's been 'transformed' to be stored in my database.

The plaintext password is:

`k4oK203$`

And the password as it is stored 'crypted' in my database is:

`6xqmRr0QNUrc0uvwGchWqA==`

How would I go about figuring out what transformation (base64? sha1? md5? etc.) that were used in order to get the plain text password in to the database value?

Comment: The trailing `==` indicates a base64 encoding, after decoding you can see the length of the binary value, the rest is try and error.

Comment: After base64 decoding it's only seven bytes, which is not any hash output length I know